# C: copy file into array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, buffer, allocation

I'm basically trying to program `sort` by myself to get myself familiarized with C. Since I'm reading from a file I thought about going at it by copying the contents of said file into an array first. I'd need to do that using `malloc` and `realloc`. So far, I have this:
(r is an option I'll be using later, but I've tried integrating it from the start)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFER 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f;
    int ram = 0;
    char **save;
    int lines=0;
    char buff[BUFFER];
    size_t size;    

    int o;
    while ((o = getopt(argc, argv, "r")) != -1) {
        switch (o) {
        case 'r': ram++; break;
        case '?': fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments\n"); exit(0);
        default: printf("Can I even go in here?\n"); break;
        }
    }
    /* argv buildup:
    argc == 3:  
    0 - prog name
    1 - opt?
    2 - filename
    3 - NULL
    */
    if (argc > (1 + ram)) {
        f = fopen(argv[1 + ram], "r");
        if (f == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File does not exist\n");
            exit(0);        
        }

        fgets(buff, BUFFER, f);
        if (buff != NULL) {
            save = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);            
            size = strlen(buff) + 1;
          /* here's the first segmentation fault */
            strcpy(save[lines], buff);
            lines++;    
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Either reached end of file or something bad happened\n");  
        }

        while ((fgets(buff, BUFFER, f)) != NULL) {
            save = realloc(save, size + strlen(buff) + 1);
            size = size + strlen(buff) + 1;
            strcpy(save[lines], buff);
            lines++;
        }       

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please start up the program correctly\n"); 
    }

}
```

As you can see from the comment in the middle of the code, I'm getting a segmentation fault at that point and I'm honestly really unsure as to why it happens. There should be enough memory available. Am I adressing that pointer wrongly? If so, how should I change it to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (buff != NULL) {
        save = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);            
        size = strlen(buff) + 1;
      /* here's the first segmentation fault */
        strcpy(save[lines], buff);
        lines++;    
    } else {
```

You've allocated the wrong amount of space for `save` and no space for the string. You want:

```
save = malloc (sizeof (char *));
*save = malloc (strlen (buff) + 1);
```

That allocates space for one string and space for the contents of that string. To add additional strings, you want:

```
save = realloc (save, (lines + 1) * sizeof (char *));
saves[lines] = malloc (strlen (buff) + 1 );
strcpy (saves[lines}, buff);
lines++;
```

That allocates space for one more string and space for the contents of that additional string.

Comment: So I'm basically allocating space for the pointer first, only to allocate space to that particular pointer later on?
If so, I'm not getting the part with realloc. Shouldn't it be something like
`save = realloc (save, (lines + 1) * sizeof (char *));` instead since I'm adding new space for each new string I want to add?

Comment: @skulpt Yes. I had an extra `*` in there.